# я новичек,просто писал код чтоб закрепить знания,а тут ошибка не понимаю где

Tags: python

```
 print("привет")
age=int(input("напиши совй возраст для продолжения "))
if (age <= 10):
    print("тебе пока нельзя")
elif (age>=10) and (age<=18):
    print("Позови взрослых")
else:
    print ("отлично")
print("хочешь узанть сколько тебе будет черз  19837 лет?")
c=int(input("1 это да 2 это нет ?"))
q1 = 1
q2 = 2
if(c(q2)):
    print("ок")
elif(c(q1)):
        def q3(age):
            return age+19837
        print(q3(age))
else:
    print("напиши да или нет")
```

Comment: Что за ошибка? Где? Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Что должен делать код? В чем ошибка? В логике? В синтаксисе? Если второе - приведите текст ошибки, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если убрать грамматические ошибки, то `c` у нас число, а вы пытаесь вызвать его как функцию. Видимо там должно быть сравнение `c == q1`

Answer (score 2):

Исправленный, улучшенный и приведенный ко всем стандартам код:

```
print("Привет")
age = int(input("Напиши свой возраст для продолжения: "))
if age <= 10:
    print("Тебе пока нельзя")
elif 10 <= age >= 18:
    print("Позови взрослых")
else:
    print("Отлично")
print("Хочешь узнать сколько тебе будет через 19837 лет?")
c = int(input("1 — это да, 2 — это нет."))
if c == 1:
   print("ок")
elif c == 2:
   print(age + 19837)
else:
    print("Неверный ввод. Нужно было написать 1 или 2.")
```

Основная ошибка (помимо кучи мелких логических) состоит в том, что вы вместо сравнения с 1 и 2 вы вызываете переменную `c`.

Comment: Вы потеряли else последнего блока if

Comment: @SwaD, не, он бессмысленен просто, на нем же программа кончается. Он бы имел смысл при while, но while-то нет.

Comment: Тут много бессмыслицы. Например при age =1 код все равно дальше пойдет...

Comment: @SwaD, ну, если следовать этой логике, то последний else действительно имел значение. Ладно, сейчас верну его.

Answer (score 1):

@SwaD правильно написал - грамматические ошибки плюс неправильное сравнение переменных. Ваш код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
def q3(age):
    return age+19837

print("привет")
age=int(input("напиши свой возраст для продолжения: "))
if (age <= 10):
    print("тебе пока нельзя")
elif (age>=10) and (age<=18):
    print("Позови взрослых")
else:
    print ("отлично")
print("хочешь узнать сколько тебе будет через  19837 лет?")
c=int(input("1 - это да; 2 - это нет"))
q1 = 1
q2 = 2
if c == q2:
    print("ок")
elif c == q1 :    
    print(q3(age))
else:
    print("напиши 1 или 2")
```

Comment: Пока писал, уже @Глеб опубликовал

Comment: Мне кажется, q3 тут не нужна, т.к. вызывается только 1 раз и сама функция в 1 строку

Comment: @SwaD, само собой, что в данном коде она лишняя, но для образовательных целей пригодится, чтобы больше различных конструкций было в коде...